# How make printable barcode template using html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, barcode-printing

I need a solution regarding barcode software that runs on node js, here i need to create a barcode printing extension for my app, the extension's run through node js. Here I need to create a specific barcode template and need to print on a particular label size. First of all i tried using html template and when i take it on print the print get enlarged and get out of the label. So we reduce the scale while printing, the printed output quality reduced. i need solution for this to print a quality barcode template with a specific sizes.

Need proper guidelines for creating an barcode template printing web application that runs in node js

Comment: Can you add in any examples of the code itself?

Comment: You have not provided enough details for us to help you. Are you using specific packages to help generate your barcodes -- if so, which ones? And what about the printing piece, how are you doing that? We are here to help you solve problems with **your** implementation, so your question needs to provide all the necessary detail for us to be able to understand your implementation and the problems with it. Questions asking us to recommend an off-site resource such as "proper guidelines" are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and will be closed.